# Rendering one of multiple pages with lit-element

Tags: lit-element

The lit-element documentation describes conditional rendering via (condition ? a : b). I was wondering how to use that to render one of multiple pages, f.e. in combination with mwc-tab-bar from Googles material web components.

My current solution is something like this:

```
render() {
    ... other stuff ...

    ${this.selectedPage === 0 ? html`
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
    ` : html``} 

    ${this.selectedPage === 1 ? html`
    <div>
        ...
    </div>            
    ` : html``}     

    ... further pages ... 
}
```

I don't like the :html`` part but is that how it's meant to be?

Comment: A short comment to my own question: in some cases you may not want to alternatively render the pages but only hide all but the selected one. For that case the hidden attribute may be used like so: <div $hidden="${this.selectedPage != 0}" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use more simple code like this.

```
constructor(){
    super();
    // don't forget add `prop` and `selectedPage` to `static get properties()`
    this.prop = 1;
}
render() {
    return this.getPage(this.selectedPage);
}

getPage(num){
    switch(num){
        default:
        case 1:
            return html`<div>P${this.prop}<div>`;
        case 2:
            return html`<div>P2<div>`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of achieving this, your solution is one, but as you mention, it's not the prettiest

One way you could modularize this somewhat is using an object/array and render functions, basically the idea is this:

First, define render functions for each page (this can be on the same file or on different files):

```
const page0Renderer = (context) => {
  return html`<section>${context.someData}</section>`;
};
```

Then, you could define an object that has a match between the page identifiers and their respective functions, you are using numbers so the sample below uses numbers:

```
const pageRenderers = {
  '0': page0Renderer,
  '1': page1Renderer,
  '2': page2Renderer,
// etc
};
```

And in your main render function you could use all these like this:

```
render() {
  return html`
    ${pageRenderers[`${this.selectedPage}`](this)}
  `;
}
```

This would basically call the render function that matches the selected page and send it a reference to the main web component so that you can access its properties.

Then again, this approach also has its flaws and I wouldn't really recommend it much if you need your child templates to be complex.

In that case, instead of rendering functions you probably would be better off creating other components for each view and that way you could also do some lazy loading and so on.

For that kind of approach, you might want to check out routers like [vaadin router](https://vaadin.com/router) which help you both with routing and changing which component gets displayed accordingly

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Since I can only accept one answer I choose HerberthObregons. Just because it is somewhat simpler for my special use case but your answer would solve it perfectly too.